# How do I get the input value of a MUI TextField with cypress?

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, cypress

I am using cypress to test that a textfield displays the entered text correctly.

```
cy.get('.creation-name').should('not.have.text');
const testName = 'Test name';
cy.get('.creation-name').type(`${testName}`);
```

TextField is a MUI component and this is a React project.

```
<div className="create-name">
    <TextField
        id="Name"
        label="Create name"
        onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
    />
</div>
```

I can see from the video that the text types in fine, but when I try to check that it's there it fails. I have tried multiple different lines to get the test text value, including these:

```
//got AssertionError for all of these
cy.get('.creation-name').invoke('val').should('equal', 'Test name');//expected '' to equal Test name
cy.contains(`${testName}`).should('have.text', `${testName}`);//expected '' to equal Test name
cy.get('[id="Name"]').should('have.text', `${testName}`);//expected '' to equal Test name
cy.get('.creation-name').invoke('text').should('equal', 'Test');//expected Create name to equal Test name
cy.get('.creation-name').should('have.text', `${testName}`);//expected Create name to equal Test name
```

Seems I am not getting anything or I am targeting the label. This is my first time using cypress so I hope I didn't miss anything obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try taking the value from the child `<input>`.

```js
cy.get('.creation-name')  // or .create-name, maybe a typo in the question
  .find('input')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('equal', 'Test name')
```

The `contains()` and text related commands won't work because it's an input, which hold the value internally.

Text commands only work for element that have the text between tags like `<div>Test text</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```js
cy.get('input[id="Name"]').invoke('val').then(value => assert.equal(value, testName));
```